# Convert a CSV to JSON and change specific key values into Boolean or string using PHP

Tags: php, json, csv

Is there a way I can change specific key values into boolean or string. The conversion changes all the Data into string. For example the Key value "Date" should be an integer instead of a string.

```
<?php 

    function csvToJson($fname) {
        if (!($fp = fopen($fname, 'r') )) {
            die("Can't open file");
        }

        $key = fgetcsv($fp, "1024", ",");

        $json = array();
            while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, "1024", ",")) {
                $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);

        foreach ( $json as $k=>$v ) {


            $json[$k]['dateRequested']     = $json[$k]['DATE']; 
            $json[$k]['assignedAgent']     = $json[$k]['AGENT'];
            $json[$k]['finalCompanyName']  = $json[$k]['COMPANY NAME'];

            unset($json[$k]['DATE']);
            unset($json[$k]['AGENT']);
            unset($json[$k]['COMPANY NAME']);


        }

        return json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    }

 ?>



<?php
$json_data = csvToJson("lms.csv");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, "1024", ",")) {
// here $row contains all the columns in it in a numeric array
// Means 0 => first column of csv, 2 => second column of csv and so on

// you can convert any specific column value like
$json[] = array($row[0], setype($row[0], "string"), and so on);
```

}

Comment: What if it is a specific "Key Value" instead of a column

Comment: Put an if block to check key value pair and do what ever you want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$json[$k]['dateRequested']     = (int)($json[$k]['DATE']); 
$json[$k]['assignedAgent']     = $json[$k]['AGENT'];
$json[$k]['finalCompanyName']  = $json[$k]['COMPANY NAME'];
```

Sample usage :

```
$int = (int)(123);
$bool = (bool)(1);
$string = (string)(1234);

var_dump($int);
var_dump($bool);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, unfortunately when using the integer it turns the value into 0

Comment: This is what the date looks like 16-09-16

Comment: the value turns into 0 because of - character.. What specific output you want? you cannot convert 16-09-16 to integer because of dash(-) character